# BorisMorel / LdapBundle is calling connect even on non-restricted area

Tags: symfony

I have integrated BorisMorel / LdapBundle version 2.0 to Symfony version 2.0.16 for `^/admin` area and it works, but there's one issue - LDAP bundle is also engaged for `^/api` which is not what I want. API should not use LDAP. I thought adding `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` for `^/api` as `access_control` option should help, but it doesn't - it is trying to connect.

**security.yml:**

```
security:
  firewalls:
    restricted_area:
      pattern:          ^/admin
      anonymous:        ~
      provider:         ldap
      imag_ldap:        ~
      form_login:
        login_path:  /login
        check_path:  /login_check
      logout:
        path:           /logout
        target:         /login

  providers:
    ldap:
      id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

  encoders:
    IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser: plaintext

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api$,  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # - { path: ^/,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

  factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/IMAG/LdapBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

imag_ldap:
  client:
    host: foo.bar.com
    port: 389
    referrals_enabled: 0
    version: 3

  user:
    base_dn: ou=user,dc=bar,dc=com
    name_attribute: uid

  role:
    base_dn: ou=user,dc=bar,dc=com
    name_attribute: cn
    user_attribute: member
```

**Question:** How can I 'turn off' LDAP for `^/api` at all?

Comment: Isn't the `$` at the end of `path: ^/api$` the problem?

Comment: ah, yes! could be! need to test it...